# Can you accumulate verbs ? Is it idiomatic ? e.g. "it has recorded and is expected to maintain exponential growth."

Tags: verbs

Should you rather write:

> It has recorded and is expected to maintain exponential growth.

Or

> It has recorded exponential growth and is expected to maintain it.

and why? I know that accumulating verbs is not an usual construction.

The first looks better to me, but some people (non-natives) have told me the first version is harder to understand. I disagree with that.

Comment: I would repeat the pronoun no matter which version you use: *… and **it** is …*

Comment: It's certainly possible to accumlate verbs. "He prepared and ate dinner last night"

Comment: There is the canonical _eats, shoots, and leaves_, of course.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - I'm going to hop, skip, and jump past that one.

Comment: @JasonBassford: That's overly fussy, unless the sentence is too long or convoluted for clarity.

Comment: While technically grammatical, the problem with #2 is that the pronoun "it" is used twice to mean two different things.  This can cause confusion over what "it" means.

Comment: @Robusto The sentence *isn't* clear without repeating the pronoun. It causes a hesitation in parsing without it, and it has nothing to do with sentence length.

Comment: @jason: That would depend on context. Consider: "Stock XYZ is a promising pick. It has recorded and is expected to maintain exponential growth." If you have any problems parsing that then you aren't paying attention, or you're reading a contextless sample which would never exist,  given that the example sentence's subject is a pronoun with no referent.

Comment: @Robusto Certainly not in this case. The sentence is more difficult to parse without the additional pronoun. Parsing shouldn't be about *having* to pay close attention. The best sentences are ones that are immediately understood without having to reread or second guess anything.

Comment: @Jason: Now you're clutching at straws. Your requirement for "close attention" may be another's walk in the park. I for one don't have any difficulty, and I'm sure I'm not alone in this. In any case,  we're talking style at this point,  so there is no "certainty" about it. The stylistic constraints your technical docs may require are hilariously out of place elsewhere. Perhaps you'll be able to admit that; perhaps not.

Comment: @Robusto No, I am not clutching at straws. If you can make something more easily understood. you should do so. Unless, of course, you are making some kind of literary statement and *want* to write in a style that is more difficult to understand in order to satisfy an intellectual purpose. And by that I don't mean that a larger vocabulary with descriptive language is bad. I'm talking about garden path statements, unclear pronoun referents, or anything else that detracts from a smooth flow and simple comprehension. Thinking about the content of words is fine; confusion over grammar is not.

Comment: @JasonBassford: It ain't about grammar, because the grammar can be parsed just fine. That appears to be where you and I differ. But I sense that you are unwilling to concede that or any point, or to find common ground. In any case your replies have ceased to be a discussion and have become a diatribe. Now they can become a monologue. Enjoy.

Comment: @Robusto Just because something *is* grammatical, that doesn't mean that it's immediately apparent to somebody that it is. Everything being equal, a sentence should be easy to read rather than difficult. There might be a good reason to make something more difficult than necessary, but that's normally the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: I actually find both versions very understandable just as they are. I'd probably write the second one myself, but that's just a subjective choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is punctuation, "and is expected to maintain" is a parenthetical comment and these are offset by commas:

It has recorded, and is expected to maintain, exponential growth.

Comment: Not sure why someone down-voted. This is the solution I would have suggested. Seems perfectly reasonable to me. I've up-voted.

Answer (score 0):

### Nonrestrictive information

Punctuating the first version of the sentence will work, but only if the meaning that's intended with *and is expected to maintain* is meant to be nonrestrictive:

- It has recorded (and is expected to maintain) exponential growth.
- It has recorded—and is expected to maintain—exponential growth.
- It has recorded, and is expected to maintain, exponential growth.

That's fine, if that's the meaning that's intended.

However, if the phrase inside the parenthetical punctuation is meant to be just as essential to the sentence as the phrase that comes before it, then the punctuation will misrepresent its importance.

---

### Mixing verbs and tenses

Encountering different verb tenses in a simple conjunction is uncommon. It's very common to find nouns joined together, and also common to find the same verb tenses joined together.

- I ate apples and pears.
- I ate and jumped.

---

Although mixing tenses is also quite common, mixing them *can* produce results, while arguably not ungrammatical, does seem odd:

- I ate and jump.

Normally, if we are mixing tenses in this way, we expand the sentence so as to give a conceptual lead-in to the second verb tense:

- First I ate, and now I jump.

Note how this turns it into a more regular set of two independent clauses.

---

### Restrictive information

The second version of the sentence in the question is straightforward:

> It has recorded exponential growth and is expected to maintain it.

That has two independent clauses, the second with an elided (but assumed) subject in the second clause. It's similar to the *first I ate, and now I jump* sentence, although slightly shortened in its syntax.

Although there are two different verb tenses being used, the construction of the sentence is such that it's not that odd to read or make out.

---

When punctuation is used with the first version of the sentence, it serves to conceptually isolate the second verb tense and phrase from the first.

Rather than interrupting your train of thought as you read the first part of the sentence, causing you to backtrack and reread it again when you get to the end—to remember what *exponential growth* has to do with the first part of the sentence—you're able to suspend the interruption of *it has recorded*, keeping both it and the parenthetical information in mind at the same time.

Without such punctuation, there is a problem:

- It has recorded and is …

At this point, you tend to slow down and get a bit confused. This isn't the typical way that mixed verbs are represented in a sentence. You start to wonder if maybe some kind of mistake has been made. It's possible that everything is fine, but you have to read the rest of the sentence in order to confirm that.

At this point, you're no longer so concerned with what's being said, as trying to determine if it's actually grammatical.

---

So, what do you do if you want to make it easier to read, but don't want to use punctuation that makes the second verb phrase parenthetical?

There are a couple of tricks that can be employed. One is to repeat the pronoun. This helps signal that there is actually a second independent clause buried in the construction. Even if the object of the two clauses is being suspended until the end of the sentence, at least it addresses the doubt you have that there is a problem:

- It has recorded and it is expected to maintain exponential growth.

Another trick is to use the word *both*, which can act as another kind of signal for a second independent clause in this case:

- It both has recorded and is expected to maintain exponential growth.

In this variation, repeating *it* is unnecessary (and even wrong), because *both* is used after the pronoun, making it clear that it should also be applied as the subject to the second verbal phrase.

---

### Conclusion

There are three overall constructions that express the idea being conveyed, but also make it easy to read:

- It has recorded exponential growth and is expected to maintain it.
- It both has recorded and is expected to maintain exponential growth.
- It has recorded, and is expected to maintain, exponential growth.

What it comes down to is if you want to conflate the two independent clauses into a construction where the object of each is suspended until the end, and if *and is expected to maintain* is meant to be nonrestrictive (parenthetical) information, or if it's equally essential to the sentence.